# Javascript circular marquee function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, marquee

I have created this script to imitate the behaviour of marquee HTML tag:

```
function MoveNoticias() {
var valorAbs = $('moverlo').offsetLeft;
var ancho = $('moverlo').getWidth();
valorAbs = Math.abs(valorAbs);
if (  valorAbs >= ancho ) {
    $('moverlo').setStyle({ left: ancho - 100 });
    valorAbs = ancho;
}
new Effect.Move('moverlo', { x: -100, y: 0, mode: 'relative' });
setTimeout(MoveNoticias, 1);
}
```

Everything is good, until this part:

```
if (  valorAbs >= ancho ) {
    $('moverlo').setStyle({ left: ancho - 100 });
    valorAbs = ancho;
}
```

The "marquee" is positioned OK, but it still blinking and fixed there, without sliding to the left.

And I do not know why, I am trying to find the way, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes a marquee is the right tool for displaying a series of photos.

Comment: @Diodeus that's not a marquee, it's a carousel

Comment: I do not know any about prototype, do you know how to fire an event after another one is complete? I am stuck with this, desease.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a clone of the content you are sliding. Then slide both of them until you reach the end of the first panel - then reset the position back to zero. Don't move it back to the original position - just set the style property directly.

Comment: You are right! I was thinking the problem trying to solve it with only one div. I will try your solution.